# How to post entries between Microsoft AX and 365 using just one system?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

How to post one entry between 2 companies where one uses Microsoft Dynamics AX and the other uses Dynamics 365 using one system?  I don't want to have to make the same entry manually to each system.

Comment: How do you think that would work?  They are essentially two unconnected systems, with two separate authorizations.

Comment: @TimRoberts this company is in the process of upgrading from 2012 to 365.  They want all records imported from 2012 to 365.  But in the mean time they are writing debt entries of one company to 2012 and credit entries of the other company to 365.